# Making an Arbitrary Identifier in neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

**Background**

I have a neo4j and spring data framework.

I have a NameType.java which extends my GraphType.java.

My GraphType.java has a `Long id` and my NameType has a `string name`

My goal is to eventually make the `String name` act as a UUID for a all things external (REST etc).

**Question**

The `Long id` is automatically made into an `@GraphId`. I want to make the `String name` in the NameType into a Arbitrary ID and as such both Unique and Indexed. I am hoping I can just annotate `@Id` to it as suggested in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#__id_arbitrary_identifier

Am I right? Is this the correct way to go about this?

Comment: So what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Id` for your uuid property, this is replacement for `@Index(primary = true, unique = true)`, it will be used for lookups when calling

- `repository.findOne("uuid")`
- `session.load(MyType.class, "uuid")`

AutoIndexManager will create correct unique constraint for that.

You still need to have a Long field for the native graph id (either name id or with `@GraphId` annotation).

Please see the [OGM docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/) for correct version (it seems that SDN docs you link include newer version of ogm docs).